# I am trying to execute a SQL query, it's have some case syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I am trying to execute this below query, but it is showing case syntax error

```
SELECT runtimeminutes,avgrating, sum(numvotes), count(*) as numberoccurences 
 CASE
  WHEN runtimeminutes BETWEEN 0 and 60 then '0-60'
  when runtimeminutes BETWEEN 61 and 120 then '61-120'
  when runtimeminutes BETWEEN 121 and 180 then '121-180'
  when runtimeminutes between 181 and 240 then '181-240'
  when runtimeminutesBETWEEN 241 and 300 then '241-300'
  else '301 and greater' 
  end as RunTimerange
FROM title_basics
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Looks like a space is missing here: `runtimeminutesBETWEEN` ?

Comment: If you are "aggegating" you need to include all non-aggregated columns in the GROUP BY clause.  In this case it probably should look like: `GROUP BY runtimeminutes, avgrating`.

Comment: You missed a `,` before CASE.